# Integration with respect to dx, dy and dz (More than one variable)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Sorry if my title was vague but i was not entirely sure what its called.

Anyways i was solving some work and energy problems and encountered this integration:

$$\int_{2,1,4}^{2,-3,3} 2x\sin^2y \,dx+ (z^2+x^2\sin2y)\,dy+ 2zy\,dz$$

Could someone explain how to solve similar integrals?
Is there something to do with partial derivatives?

The book gave the answer saying it was of form

$$\int_{2,1,4}^{2,-3,3} d(x^2\sin^2y + z^2y)$$

I cant quite understand how that integral came.

In some cases we can split up the integral into $dx$ and $dy$ and integrate separately. Is it possible to do here?

Comment: This is a line integral.

Comment: You are adding up the projection of a vector field along a given curve, that some object traverses.

Comment: write the parametric equation of the path then proceed

Comment: In general, an integral like the one given depends on the path between the endpoints. Since the integrand is an exact differential of a function (as given in the book) the integral does not depend on the path, and is just equal to the difference between the values of the function at the two endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have stated that the field that does work on the object is conservative, and if it is then differential amounts of work done can be written as $dF$ where it is presented to you in an expanded form like on the right hand side below.

$$dF(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz$$

We need to match the terms above with that given in the problem and find F.

Then equating terms

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=2zy$$

Integrating

$$F(x,y,z)=yz^2+h(x,y)$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=z^2+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=z^2+x^2sin(2y)$$

Integrating we find

$$h(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2cos(2y)+g(x)$$

$$F(x,y,z)=yz^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2cos(2y)+g(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=-xcos(2y)+g'(x)=2xsin^2(y)$$

$$g'(x)=x(2sin^2(y)+cos(2y))$$

Using a double angle formula

$$g'(x)=x(2sin^2(y)+cos^2(y)-sin^2(y))=x(sin^2(y)+cos^2(y))=x$$

$$g'(x)=x$$

$$g(x)=x^2/2$$

$$F(x,y,z)=yz^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2cos(2y)+x^2/2$$

Recognizing $1-Cos(2y)=1-Cos^2(y)+Sin^2(y)=2Sin^2(y)$ and substituting you get

$$F(x,y,z)=yz^2+x^2sin^2(y)$$

Comment: All right! Thanks.